# the following quesion which one is not correct?

Tags: c++

After reading so many times, I still think all the choices are correct. So where I am wrong? Or is the question wrong?

> *. About the inheritance, which one is not correct?
>
> A. The protected inheritance can be used to protect members in base class
>
> B. The object of derived class can access all the public member of base class
>
> C. The pointer of a base class can be assigned by address of a derived class
>
> D. The private derived class can use the protected members of its base class
> *

Comment: Is there context here that provides meaning to the word "protect" in A? Because I'm pretty sure it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Frank yeah, teachers make up their own jargon as they go and assume everyone understands that. Stuff like this doesn't teach anyone anything. Teachers should just be straight about that and say "Protected members are only accessible within derived classes". Using flowery language no one understands is hardly useful.

Comment: apart from C, all possible answers can be checked by trying and see what the compiler has to tell (though I do agree, A is rather unclear)

Comment: I agree with 蒋浩楠 that all answers are true. Is this a translation from another language? If so, is it possible that there's an error in the translation? Otherwise, I've often found lecturers/tutors make errors in questions and marking. They're human too.

Comment: @蒋浩楠 Try going to Compiler Explorer https://godbolt.org/ and setting up the above as simple test cases eg this is my understanding of case (D) https://godbolt.org/z/cd939r41a

Answer (score -1):

maybe I have known the correct answer?Only public inheritance can the object of drived class use the public members of base class in main stack or some where else?

Comment: Hi 蒋浩楠, welcome to stack overflow. Your question's a good one, however you should only post answers when you're somewhat sure that the answer is correct, and you provide the justification. Posting your answer as a question will just lead to you being downvoted, So I suggest removing this answer or editing it to be more assertive and with justifications.  =)